# Visualizing the SiteMap of a large (page number) website

Tags: sitemap, visualization, data-visualization

I'm looking for a tool or service that can spider a web domain with a large number of pages, create a sitemap, and then visualize that map in a way that will help me see, understand and group content (I'm new to the site)  Something like a tree-view or other standard Site Map visualizations would be great.  I am yet unable to find a tool that does this (I've found plenty of things to spider the site and create an xml file, nothing to visualize it)

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how large is large? 100 pages? 1000? 10000? more?

Answer (score 2):

The software [Gephi](http://www.gephi.org) and [one of its plugins](http://gephi.org/plugins/http-graph/) provides exactly the function that you need.

Answer (score 1):

For visualization you can check D3.js

For example [Force-Directed Graph](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html)

Answer (score 0):

Visualize website structure you can with [Site Visualizer](http://site-visualizer.com) software.

Download and install it, then create new project and click Start toolbutton. After the site will be crawled, open Visual Sitemap tab and click Draw button. Visual map of the site will be created as a set of pages (rectangles) and links (arrows). Click on a rectangle in order to highlight all outbound links of the page. You can also save this visualization to an image file: png, jpg, bmp, etc.:

[image: site map visualization]

Comment: This program crashed my computer when I tried to use it on a large site.  Tried a second time and same results.

Comment: What is the site you're trying to crawl?

Comment: @dcc, you can also [contact](http://site-visualizer.com/help/contacts) the support team, and we'll help you with crawling of any website.